# Representing a TIN in GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, tin

Regarding the GeoJSON representation of a TIN, are there

1. any specifications or
2. existing implementations I may not be aware of?

You could probably hack one together using the multipolygon feature type, but this seems inefficient.

Generally speaking, I don't see any surface types (regular or irregular) represented in the GeoJSON world, is there any existing or upcoming work in this area?

Comment: you could ask to the geojson mailing list: http://lists.geojson.org/listinfo.cgi/geojson-geojson.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a GeoJSON spec out for TIN, but there is one for WKT. Basically, `TIN` is a synonym for `MultiPolygon`, and `Triangle` is a synonym for `Polygon`.

Thus a four node, two element TIN can be encoded with the WKT:

```
TIN Z (((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)), ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 0 0 0)))
```

Which *should* translate to:

```
{"type":"TIN","coordinates":[[[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]],[[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,0]]]]}
```

With the OGC WKT specification, each triangle has one linear ring, with four vertices. (Rant: a triangle has only one linear ring and three vertices, and I'm unsure why OGC ignored these facts before inflating the storage size).